# Change the background color of a control when the bound field's data is changed

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework

I have a BindingSource (related with an entity ) , and on the form , some control bound to it.

Sometimes the data on bindingsource is changed directly ( not from changing bound control's value )

How can I do that when the data of current object on bindingSource is updated , the corresponding controls in the form bound to changed fields ,  change the background color for example to Red?

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

there is an event to control when  datasource or datamember of a bindingsource is changed.in that event u can change the attributes of control.here is a sample

```
Private Sub BindingSource1_DataSourceChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As  System.EventArgs) Handles BindingSource1.DataSourceChanged

Form.Urcontrol.BackColor = Color.Red

End Sub
```

hope this will help.

Comment: What is UrControl ? The problem is how to find the control that is bound to filed that has changed